# Convert excel to xml in php

Tags: php, xml, excel

I want to read an Excel file and create an XML file from that data.
Is it possible in php?

Thanks

Comment: If you're talking about xlsx documents than you already have zipped xml files. Besides that: what have to tried? What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

Quick Google search found [this PHP](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) project on CodePlex, you may want to take a look

It supports:

> ...write to and read from different spreadsheet file formats, like Excel
>   (BIFF) .xls, Excel 2007 (OfficeOpenXML) .xlsx, CSV, Libre/OpenOffice
>   Calc .ods, Gnumeric, PDF, HTML, ... This project is built around
>   Microsoft's OpenXML standard and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I dont know about any existing libs for php to convert them.

There is some information about excel file formats, so you can write some code

old one : http://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf
new one : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

this can give you a start : http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/ :)