# How to convert .xlsx file to .xml file using php?

Tags: php, xml, file, xlsx, file-conversion

Is there any way I can able to convert .xlsx file to .xml using PHP?

I will just upload a xlsx document file which should be converted to xml file

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621661/convert-excel-to-xml-in-php

Comment: So find a library that can parse xlsx files, like PHPExcel, and write a script that uses that library to read the spreadsheet and create the xml structured as you need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [the PHPExcel spreadsheet engine](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

It will alow you to read different file formats into your spreadsheet object

- **Excel 2007 (spreadsheetML)**
- BIFF5 (Excel 5.0 / Excel 95), BIFF8 (Excel 97 and higher)
- PHPExcel Serialized Spreadsheet
- Excel 2003 XML format
- Open Office Calc (.ods)
- Gnumeric
- Symbolic Link (SYLK)
- CSV (Comma Separated Values)

as well as to output your spreadsheet object to different file formats

- Excel 2007 (spreadsheetML)
- BIFF8 (Excel 97 and higher)
- PHPExcel Serialized Spreadsheet
- CSV (Comma Separated Values)
- HTML
- PDF

I think it's definitely worth a look and might get you going. Good luck!